# Apache SSL "Unable get local issuer certificate" on Debian

Tags: apache, security, ssl, debian

I'm using RapidSSL with apache2 (2.2.22-13+deb7u6). I got three files from rapidssl - public.crt, private.key and rapid_intermediate.crt.

My public.crt looks like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIErjCCA5agAwIBAgIDBthaMA0GCSqSAwHgYDVQQDExdSYXBpZFNTTCBTSEEy
NTYgQ0EgLSBHMzAeFw0xNTA5MTAwMDU0NTJaFw0xNjA5MTExNTM1NTNaMIGTMRMw
EQYDVQQLEwpHVDM5ODg2NjMwMTEwLwYDVQQLEyhTZWUgd3d3LnJhcGlkc3NsLmNv
bS9yZXNvdXJjZXMvY3BzIChjKTE1MS8wLQYDVQQLEyZLm1lbG9tYXAuY29t
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvDo9jDb+k/dHqp7FW7dW
V9+W6a1Ut3OKC3wCulac+WG2roxZukuA42LQ4fAY/BDtBkk2UQ5IyFpFzmCiXjBu
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

My private.key looks like

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MdddddIBAAKCAQEAvDo9jDb+k/dHqp7FW7dddddddddPvuSy2aEJcHbt2kb6UI
ddddddd7dWVQ84DlVPvuSy2aEJcHbt2kb6UIdddddddddAKCAQEAvDMIIEowIB
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

My RapidSSL intermediate looks like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEZZZZZZZgAwIBAgIDAjp3MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
MRYwFAYSSSSSSS1HZW9UcnVzdCBJbmMuMRswGQYDVQQSSSSSZW9UcnVzdCBHbG9i
YWwgQ0EwHhcNMTQwODI5MjEzOTMyWhcNMjIwNTIwMjEzOTMyWjBHMQswCQYDVQQG
EwJVUzEWMBQGA1UEChMNR2VvVHJ1c3QgSW5jLjEgMB4GA1UEAxMXUmFwaWRTU0wg
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In my apache config,

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt/public.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt/rapid_intermediate.crt
```

However, I'm still getting the following errors.

```
unable to get local issuer certificate
certificate not trusted
unable to verify the first certificate
```

Please let me know what I did wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be careful about giving out some of the bits of your private key.  Research has shown that [exposing a fraction of the private key bits](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.40.1461&rep=rep1&type=pdf) can lead to complete compromise of the key.

Comment: @TheGreatContini, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Check the chain order, sometimes the chain is unsorted or need an additional certificate in chain, if you server is public you can use sslchecker.com to check